# Bash:source files without fullpath?

Tags: bash, shell-script

if I source the script file without pre-path definition, it does not work. What is happening below? I have got a go1 function in the file simply printing $PWD.

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.48(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin12)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
$ source functions.sh
$ go1
-bash: go1: command not found
$ source ./functions.sh
$ go1
Current dir is /Users/mert/temp
$
```

Comment: What's the contents of `functions.sh`?

Comment: @Herman go1(){
    echo "Current dir is $PWD";
}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you might have a file named `functions.sh` in one of the directories in your `$PATH`.

- `source functions.sh` runs the one in your path, so go1 is not defined
- `source ./functions.sh` runs the one you expect and go1 is defined.

This little script might help.

```
P=`env | egrep -e'^PATH' | sed -e 's/^PATH=//' `

IFS=:
for i in $P
do
 if [[ -f $i/functions.sh ]] 
 then 
   ls -l $i/functions.sh
 fi
done
```

Comment: you are right,thanks, I had one with the same name in the PATH. so "source" looks up in the path and then file system?

Comment: if /Users/mert/scripts/functions.sh was not set excutable then which wouldn't find it, this is why I gave you the little script. BTWI never put dot into my path for fear of running something I didn't intend, and always explicitely use the ./commandname syntax whilst developing a script.

Comment: BTW, why not just execute P=`echo $PATH` in the first line

Comment: Yes, that would be simpler, I wrote it quickly. btw to answer your last question, It was because when saying ./functions.sh you are explicitly defining the path to the current directory, omitting dot then PATH is searched.